# Best way to add custom transition when adding view to linearlayout?

Tags: android, animation, android-linearlayout

I have a LinearLayout which contains several views. When I add a new view to the linearlayout programmatically, I want it to fade out the last view on the right, and to move in the new view from the top (translateY). What is the best way to implement this intro/exit transition that works from API 14+?

Comment: i am also searching for it, i will prefer circle-reveal transition, but it is applied in >=21